# How do I contextualize the Fuel SDK to retrieve event data for a specific user?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, oauth2, fuel-sdk

Is it possible to get the Ruby FuelSDK to query for, say, the subscribers or events of another user who has installed an app?  Do I simply need to set the internal_token?

```
fuelsdk_client = FuelSDK::Client.new({'client' => {
    'id' => ENV['ET_CLIENT_ID'], 
    'secret' => ENV['ET_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    'signature' => ENV['ET_APP_SIGNATURE']
  }})
fuelsdk_client.internal_token = "0z..."
sdk = FuelSDK::OpenEvent.new
sdk.authStub = fuelsdk_client
events_response = sdk.get
```

If I set `internal_token` above to the `internalOauthToken` from a decoded JWT captured when the user logged in, will `events_response` be contextualized properly to return events for that user?

Answer (score 0):

After reverse engineering for a while, the answer I've come up with is:

```
raise "Need Client ID in environment" if ENV['ET_CLIENT_ID'].nil?
fuelsdk_client = FuelSDK::Client.new ({'client' => {
  'id' => ENV['ET_CLIENT_ID'], 
  'secret' => ENV['ET_CLIENT_SECRET']
}})

fuelsdk_client.internal_token = exacttarget_internal_oauth_token
fuelsdk_client.access_token = exacttarget_oauth_token
fuelsdk_client.refresh_token = exacttarget_refresh_token
fuelsdk_client.auth_token_expiration = exacttarget_token_expiration_date
```

BUT this is hard to actually take advantage of, because the client will refresh the token silently sometimes, and you need to know to store off those values whenever they do.  The way you get them is via:

```
exacttarget_internal_oauth_token = fuelsdk_client.internal_token
exacttarget_oauth_token = fuelsdk_client.access_token
exacttarget_refresh_token = fuelsdk_client.refresh_token
exacttarget_token_expiration_date = fuelsdk_client.auth_token_expiration
```

But WHEN to get them, that's trickier...

EDIT: I ended up forking FuelSDK-Ruby to add a callback so it would notify me whenever it chose to update.  I then store the values in a database for use by other jobs.  Feel free to try the [fork](https://github.com/Vestorly/FuelSDK-Ruby) or just check out the relevant [commit](https://github.com/Vestorly/FuelSDK-Ruby/commit/76216ff6a9a6c95f827b65146451cef25c6a870b).

EDIT 2: See my more complete answer here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/96980/19068